# Transferring information from one table to another using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database **my_db** and in it two tables **t1** and **t2**.

**t1** has two columns *ID* and *count*. *ID* is a list of some integers, say 1,3,4,6,7,8,9 and *count*  is all 0s by default.

**t2** also has two columns, *ID2* which has a list of integers which are same as that of *ID* in **t1**. But, it is possible that they may repeat or may not be present. The second column contains some value, that isn't of much importance to this question. Clarification: *ID2* can be 1,1,3,4,3,1,9,8,7,7,7.

Now, what I need to do is for every *ID* in **t1** I need to fill in *count*, i.e., the number of occurrences of *ID* as *ID2* in **t2**.

Running a loop through all the values in *ID2* and incrementing by 1 every time in corresponding *count* ought to do it. But I'm unable to code it up, being new to php and sql. I can work in one table. How to work across multiple?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you use two tables?

Comment: @andershagbard Yup! This is just a scaled down version of a bigger problem.

Comment: If you can provide some concrete example (preferably with numbers) for what you have on input and what you expect on output, we can give you answer very quickly, and I expect that this can be done in SQL only

Comment: Taking the above example itself, the expected output in the form of rows: (1,3),(3,2),(4,1),(6,0),(7,3),(8,1),(9,1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try MySQL update join?

```
UPDATE t1 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT id2, 
                         Count(1) AS num 
                  FROM   t2 
                  GROUP  BY id2) ref 
              ON t1.id = ref.id2 
SET    t1.count = ref.num
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: All the answers given were correct, but I checked this one, since it was easy to understand for me and was earlier in chronological order. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

### Are you looking for this :

```
select t1.id,count(t2.id) as total_record_in_t2
from t1
     left join t2 on (t1.id=t2.id)
group by t1.id;
```

[SQL Fiddle Example - Click to See](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a266b/3)

Answer (score 2):

As I have understand your question is that, you need to count all ID's from Table t2 by looking ID in table t1 and then you want to insert the count of all ID's in your count column of table t1.

```
<?php 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from t1");
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($query )) {

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) from t2 WHERE id='".$record['ID']."'");
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
$count = $fetch['COUNT(*)'];

$query3 = mysql_query("UPDATE t1 SET count='".$count."' WHERE id='".$record['ID']."'");

}

?>
```

If you get any error. You may inform me.

Hope it will works for you.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another answer (with sub query)

```
update d1
set d1.count_d1 = (select count(d2.id)
                   from d2
                   where d2.id = d1.id group by d1.id)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa454/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sql part.
First get the count of occurences of ID2 in t2:

```
select id2, count(*) from ts group by id2;
```

Then loop over the result and update t1:

```
update t1 set count = $value where id1 = $id2
```